ReactJS and HTML - How to only allow letters on input?
I want the input field to only populate with letters. If you try type in a number, or a special character, nothing is input into the field.
I want this to be validated AS I am typing, NOT validated on submit.
My current code works for the console.log, only logging letter presses.
But the input field still populates.
My current code:
export default function GuessApp() {

    function alphaOnly(e) {
        if (/[a-zA-Z]/i.test(e.key)) {
            console.log(e.key)
            return e.key
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <form className="border">
                <input className="border border-black w-8 h-8 text-center uppercase" type="text" maxLength="1" onKeyDown={alphaOnly}></input>
            </form>
        </>
    )
}

I keep seeing a "solution" of onkeydown="return /[a-z]/i.test(event.key)"
However, I just get an error that onKeyDown requires a function, string given.

The input field still populates because you're not using state to control the input value.
Here’s an updated version of your code with controlled state:
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function GuessApp() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  function onChange(e) {
    const value = e.target.value;
    if (/^[a-zA-Z]*$/.test(value)) {
      setInputValue(value);
    }
  }

  return (
    <form className="border">
      <input
        className="border border-black w-8 h-8 text-center uppercase"
        type="text"
        maxLength="1"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </form>
  );
}


Thank you, I had tried state, but missed the crucial step of setting the value={}.
Now, I need to figure out how to scale this so that all inputs have the same rules, but don't all change at the same time.
